# Using sed to replace a pattern by symbol

Tags: linux, sed

How do I replace a pattern by looking at sentence symbol by using sed?
Input

```
this-
-this-
```

Results I want

```
start
middle
```

My code

```
sed 's/[a-zA-Z]-/start/g'
sed 's/-[a-zA-Z]-/middle/g'
```

Results I get

```
abastart
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Doing the substitutions in the opposite order would trivially solve this, as long as the replacement string can't produce a result which matches the other pattern (but if it does, you have a problem regardless).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
sed -r 's/^[a-zA-Z]+-/start/;s/^-[a-zA-Z]+-/middle/' file
start
middle
```

- `-r` or `-E` for extended regex
- `+` to tell its 1 or more character
- `^` to tell to start from beginning of line
- `;` to have more than one `sed` block in one line
- You can add `$` to make sure whole line is matched `s/^[a-zA-Z]+-$/start/`

Comment: If you anchor with `$` you can drop the `g`. You can also use the `\w` character shorthand, e.g. `sed -E 's/^\w+-$/start/;s/^-\w+-$/middle/' file`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `\w` do also match number, and since OP posted  `[a-zA-Z]`, I stick with that. And `g` can be removed even if `$` is not used, but that may depend if OP test against more in the same line.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, so if there are any numbers in the file `[a-zA-Z]` is the way to go. `\w` also matches `'_'`.

Comment: `[[:alpha:]]` is another way or writing `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without '-r' or '-E'? Just sed 's/^[a-zA-Z]+-/start/' file

Comment: @Hal, no.  Does you sed not support extended regex?  It can be done with `awk` if  `sed` does not work.

Comment: @potong.  Yes that is true.

Comment: I managed to use sed without -r by changing + to *. I don't actually know how it works but it worked.