# Replace each column with different spacing using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to replace a different pattern for each column of my input file.

Input file

```
this- START
this-        START
```

Result I want

```
/this/ -START-
/this/ -START-
```

My code

```
sed 's|^\([a-zA-Z]*\)-\s\([a-zA-Z]*\)$|/\1/ -\2-|' inputfile
```

Output

```
/this/ -START-
this-        START
```

The first input works but the 2nd input with a huge amount of spaces does not. How can I deal with both of them using the same line of code?

Comment: This is just a follow up on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57533157/using-sed-to-replace-a-pattern-by-symbol  You stil missing `-r` or `-E` when using extended regex like `[a-zA-Z]`.  You did not respond if you could use `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions, which are, like the name suggests, very basic, without a lot of the syntactical sugar or features of other RE packages you might be more used to. But they can still handle this:

```
$ cat input.txt
this- START
this-           START
$ sed 's!^\([a-zA-Z]*\)-[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([a-zA-Z]*\)$!/\1/ -\2-!' input.txt
/this/ -START-
/this/ -START-
```

The key here is in the `[[:space:]]\{1,\}` portion: `[:space:]` inside a `[]`character class matches any whitespace character, like `\s` in other RE implementations, and `\{1,\}` matches 1 or more of the preceeding atom, like `+` in pretty much every other flavor (Which also support this notation, though without needing the backslashes). So combined it matches 1 or more whitespace characters. And since regular expressions are greedy, it matches the longest sequence of whitespace characters instead of stopping after seeing just one.

If you only have spaces, not spaces and/or tabs between columns, it can be simplified to `\{1,\}` (Note the leading literal space; it's not obvious in rendered markdown). And you can use `[[:alpha:]]` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` to match all alphabetic characters. Makes a difference if matching non-English text. And you might want to use `\{1,\}` instead of `*` to avoid matching 0-length/missing columns if they can show up in your input.